# why harbor give 405 method not allowed when login in web page

Tags: kubernetes

I am installed harbor in my kubernetes v1.18 cluster, what makes me confusing is that when I login harbor using default username and password: `admin/Harbor123456`, it give me error: `405 Method Not Allowed`.

[image]

405 is show that you should using `GET` but actuallly using `POST` error, I do not think the harbor login page would make this mistake.why would this happen and what should I do to fix it? By the way, This is the kubernetes traefik config:

```
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
  routes:
    - kind: Rule
      match: Host(`harbor-portal.dolphin.com`)
      services:
        - name: harbor-harbor-portal
          port: 80
    - kind: Rule
      match: Host(`harbor-portal.dolphin.com`) && PathPrefix(`/c`)
      services:
        - name: harbor-harbor-core
          port: 80
    - kind: Rule
      match: Host(`harbor-portal.dolphin.com`) && PathPrefix(`/v2`)
      services:
        - name: harbor-harbor-core
          port: 80
    - kind: Rule
      match: Host(`harbor-portal.dolphin.com`) && PathPrefix(`/api`)
      services:
        - name: harbor-harbor-core
          port: 80
    - kind: Rule
      match: Host(`harbor-portal.dolphin.com`) && PathPrefix(`/service`)
      services:
        - name: harbor-harbor-core
          port: 80
    - kind: Rule
      match: Host(`harbor-portal.dolphin.com`) && PathPrefix(`/chartrepo`)
      services:
        - name: harbor-harbor-core
          port: 80
```

the kubernetes ingress is traefik 2.2.1. This is the log output of harbor portal in kubernetes pod:

```
2020-08-03T16:50:17.415502118Z  10.11.157.67 - - [03/Aug/2020:16:50:17 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 856 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
2020-08-03T16:50:18.242118851Z  192.168.31.30 - - [03/Aug/2020:16:50:18 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 856 "-" "kube-probe/1.18"
2020-08-03T16:50:18.307214547Z  192.168.31.30 - - [03/Aug/2020:16:50:18 +0000] "POST /c/login HTTP/1.1" 405 559 "http://harbor-portal.dolphin.com/harbor/sign-in?redirect_url=%2Fharbor%2Fprojects" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
2020-08-03T16:50:19.233495082Z  192.168.31.30 - - [03/Aug/2020:16:50:19 +0000] "POST /c/login HTTP/1.1" 405 559 "http://harbor-portal.dolphin.com/harbor/sign-in?redirect_url=%2Fharbor%2Fprojects" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
```

send the request from harbor portal kubernetes pod:

```
nginx [ / ]$   curl -X POST 'http://localhost:8080/c/login' \
>   -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
>   -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
>   -H 'DNT: 1' \
>   -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36' \
>   -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
>   -H 'Origin: http://harbor-portal.dolphin.com' \
>   -H 'Referer: http://harbor-portal.dolphin.com/harbor/sign-in?redirect_url=%2Fharbor%2Fprojects' \
>   -H 'Accept-Language: en,zh-CN;q=0.9,zh;q=0.8,zh-TW;q=0.7,fr;q=0.6' \
>   --data-raw 'principal=admin&password=Harbor123456' \
>   --compressed \
>   --insecure
<html>
<head><title>405 Not Allowed</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>405 Not Allowed</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.16.1</center>
</body>
</html>
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
```

Comment: check the harbor logs to see if the traffic is reaching to harbor or is Treafik doing something in between.

Comment: I request from kubernetes pod, it still give 405 error. so I do not thing it is a traefik problem. @TarunKhosla

Comment: https://github.com/goharbor/harbor-helm/issues/485 , looks like an open issue here

Comment: I have already read this topic and still do not known how to solve it.@TarunKhosla

Comment: The issue is open , it means it is still being figured out so keep calm and wait for them to resolve it.

Comment: ok.thank you! but I think this problem is so obviously and it is unpossible happen.@TarunKhosla

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219182/discussion-between-dolphin-and-tarun-khosla).

Answer (score 1):

I installed harbor(v1.10.4) by helm with alb ingress. When login with correct user&password it returns 405 error.
Followed this issue(https://github.com/goharbor/harbor-helm/issues/485#issuecomment-686222551), I solved this question. The key reason is that ingress rules leads login request to portal. Just change the portal related rule to the buttom could sovle it.

origin ingress:

```
spec:
  rules:
  - host: harbor.xxx.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: harbor-harbor-portal
          servicePort: 80
        path: /*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
      - backend:
          serviceName: harbor-harbor-core
          servicePort: 80
        path: /api/*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
      - backend:
          serviceName: harbor-harbor-core
          servicePort: 80
        path: /service/*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
      - backend:
          serviceName: harbor-harbor-core
          servicePort: 80
        path: /v2/*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
      - backend:
          serviceName: harbor-harbor-core
          servicePort: 80
        path: /chartrepo/*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
      - backend:
          serviceName: harbor-harbor-core
          servicePort: 80
        path: /c/*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```

after modify:

```
spec:
  rules:
  - host: harbor.xxx.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: harbor-harbor-core
          servicePort: 80
        path: /api/*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
      - backend:
          serviceName: harbor-harbor-core
          servicePort: 80
        path: /service/*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
      - backend:
          serviceName: harbor-harbor-core
          servicePort: 80
        path: /v2/*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
      - backend:
          serviceName: harbor-harbor-core
          servicePort: 80
        path: /chartrepo/*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
      - backend:
          serviceName: harbor-harbor-core
          servicePort: 80
        path: /c/*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
      - backend:
          serviceName: harbor-harbor-portal
          servicePort: 80
        path: /*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```